# I am trying to make a chess clock in C but both times running

Tags: c, time, clock

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<windows.h>

const int milisec = 1000;

int main() {

  char cc = '\0';

  int wsec, wmin, bsec, bmin, choice;

  wsec = 0;
  bsec = 0;

  int* mp = &wmin;
  int* sp = &wsec;

  do {
    printf("\nReloj de Ajedrez de Leo, seleccione un ritmo de juego:\n");
    printf("1.-Blitz (3:00)\n");
    printf("2.-Blitz (5:00)\n");
    printf("3.-Rapida (10:00)");

    printf("\nSeleccione su opcion:");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    system("cls");

    switch (choice) {

    case 1: wmin = 3; bmin = 3; break;
    case 2: wmin = 5; bmin = 5; break;
    case 3: wmin = 10, bmin = 10; break;
    default: printf("\nOpcion Incorrecta, seleccione nuevamente.\n");
    }

  } while (choice > 3 || choice < 1);


  while (true) {
    if (kbhit()) {
      cc = getch();
    }

    printf("\nWHITE: %d:%d       BLACK: %d:%d", wmin, wsec, bmin, bsec);

    Sleep(milisec);

    if (*sp == 0) {
      --* mp;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////WHY ?

    *sp == 0 ? *sp = 59 : -- * sp;

    system("cls");

    if (cc == 'l') {
      mp == &wmin ? mp = &bmin : mp = &wmin;
      sp == &wsec ? sp = &bsec : sp = &wsec;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Please I am trying to make a chess clock but the third time I press a key it is both times that start to run down.... Help

I mean, the pinter I am using is changing isnt it?

PS: Please, rate how readable it is, I know it's a bit messy but Im trying to improve

and the genius SO is asking me mre details, ffs LOL.

Comment: "Please, rate how readable it is," With all those tons of empty lines and broken indentation readability is really bad. Also, please don't include code that is not relevant for the question, e.g. the first loop is useless for your problem. Always provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *rate how readable it is* - the excessive amount of empty lines and the inconsistent indentation makes it hard to read and therefore hard to help. We're even forced to scroll through your code which basically should fit on a page. Invest some time to learn about code formatting. It's not only a matter of beauty, but helps you to see the structure and recognize mistakes much faster.

Comment: *the genius SO is asking me mre details, ffs LOL.* - doesn't seem like you really understand why you're asked for more details and the LOL indicates that you don't take it seriously. If you seriously want help then consider reading [ask] and how to provide a [mre] and improve the question. Otherwise it might end up downvoted and closed quite soon.

Comment: Without analyzing the rest of the code, it seems you messed up using the conditional operator `? :`. Instead do: `mp = mp == &wmin ? &bmin : &wmin;` `sp = sp == &wsec ? &bsec : &wsec;`

Comment: _Please, rate how readable it is:_ my rating of readability: maybe 3 out of 10. I reformatted it properly mostly be removing the pointless empty lines. For code formatting get inspired by the samples in your learning material.

Comment: My attempt to compile this with MSVC failed at the two ternary operator lines, so I don't see how you could have run the code.

Comment: I personally would rather use a struct containing minutes and seconds and have one single pointer to one of two of these structs, you need to swap just once that way and keep closely related data together.

Comment: conio.h, `system("cls")` means this is windows specific and I suggest you tag it as such

Comment: @Aconcagua Your link was to an empty code sheet but it seems GCC [rejects](https://godbolt.org/z/joncoYPdY) it. It would be ok in C++ though. Perhaps you had in C++ mode?

Comment: @AllanWind I wouldn't tag it "Windows" as the problem isn't Windows specific. IMO tagging C is good enough

Comment: @Jabberwocky If you don't run windows you can't run ops code.  I am on Linux so I ignore questions tagged windows.  Appreciate your input even if we may not necessarily agree.

Comment: @AllanWind fair enough, but the actual problem isn't Windows specific though.

Comment: I suggest you just have a variable for seconds (for each side; or maybe array with two elements) and on display format the seconds to M:H.  Your main problem is going to be that you need 3 things to happen at the same time: display a counting clock, listening for input, and trigger an alarm when time is up.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh, indeed, was C++ mode ;) Interesting enough, C++ has different operator precedence here (C can be fixed by adding parentheses).

Answer (score 3):

Dropping all code irrelevant for illustrating the problem:

```
if (kbhit())
{
    cc = getch();
}
if (cc == 'l')
{
    mp == &wmin ? mp = &bmin : mp = &wmin;
    sp == &wsec ? sp = &bsec : sp = &wsec;
}
```

And when do you reset `cc`???

The point is once `cc` is set it will remain there until someone enters another character than `l` and your clock remains toggling with every millisecond! That's a pretty quick toggling time, by the way, most likely `Sleep` won't be that precise itself! You might want to consider longer sleeping times and instead fix any imprecision by checking how many milliseconds actually elapsed by some high precision clock. In any case: To fix, you need to reset the input within the loop; however: You run much less probably into such errors as this one if you limit the scope of variables to not any wider than actually needed; in given case, if you had moved the variable *into* the loop (there are exceptions to this rule, e.g. it is preferable to just clear an existing container instead of constructing and destructing it again and again):

```
for(;;)
{
    if(kbhit())
    {
        char cc = getch();
        if(cc == 'l')
        {
            // TODO: switch your pointers right here!
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Side note: Consider rather letting the users press the space bar, it is much larger and thus simpler to hit – or accept just *any* character.

I additionally recommend using a struct containing both minutes and seconds:

```
typedef struct Duration
{
    int min;
    int sec;
} Duration;
```

for each player, this way you need to exchange just one single pointer. Usually you'd do so rather this way:

```
activeDuration = activeDuration == &white ? &black : &white;
```

Actually even better is one single integer containing minutes converted to seconds (e.g. 300 seconds for 5-minute 'Blitz'; thanks @Allan Wind for that hint), you don't have to care for overflow any more and can print out both minutes and seconds from that value on, e.g. like 
`printf("%d:%d", sec / 60, sec % 60);`.

Instead of switching pointers I personally like using an index into an array pretty much, by the way:

```
Duration durations[2];
unsigned int activeDuration = 0;

// use durations[activeDuration];

// toggle by:
activeDuration = 1 - activeDuration;
```

Comment: Thank you su much my friend. Muchas Gracias Aconcagua!